# Getting error after trying to read the response in HTTP post

Tags: http, at-command, modem

I'm working on HTTP protocol in PIC24F microcontroller interfacing with M95 quectel modem.

I'm trying the "POST" method. I've read the datasheet of HTTP protocol of quectel.

Below are the send HTTP post Request AT commands:

```
AT+QIFGCNT
AT+QHTTPURL
AT+QHTTPPOST
AT+QHTTPREAD
AT+QIDEACT
```

I write the code according to this flow sequence. I put those commands in infinite while loop. 
Ok the first time I read the response from the server successfully, but later I get an error like "http response failed" or
"http get no request" at AT+QHTTPREAD.

Do I have to repeat the whole HTTP post AT commands or I just to repeat AT+QHTTPREAD only?

CODE:

```
bool SendAtCommand_Response(char *command, char *response,int Delay);

    while(1)
{

                SendAtCommand_Response("AT\r","OK",500);
                uart1str("Modem is ready\r\n");
                Delayms(2000);
                uart1str("\r\n");
                clear();                        //clear response buffer
                SendAtCommand_Response("AT+CPIN?\r","OK",2000);
                Delayms(300);
                uart1str("\r\n");
                clear();
                SendAtCommand_Response("AT+QIFGCNT=0\r","OK",500);
                Delayms(300);
                uart1str("\r\n");
                clear();
                SendAtCommand_Response("AT+QICSGP=1,\"airtelGPRS.com\"\r","OK",500);
                Delayms(500);
                uart1str("APN is set\r\n");
                uart1str("\r\n");
                clear();
                SendAtCommand_Response("AT+QHTTPURL=37,30\r","CONNECT",500);
                uart1str("URL is set\r\n");
                clear();
                SendAtCommand_Response(HTTP_POST_URL_HS ,"OK",500);
                Delayms(500);
                uart1str("URL Sent\r\n");
                clear();
                SendAtCommand_Response("AT+QHTTPPOST=22,25,10\r","CONNECT",1000);
                Delayms(1000);
                uart1str("\r\n");
                clear();
                SendAtCommand_Response("imeino=865733024598757","OK",100);
                Delayms(1000);
                uart1str("HTTP data sent\r\n");
                uart1str("\r\n");
                clear();
                SendAtCommand_Response("AT+QHTTPREAD=30\r","CONNECT",3000);
                Delayms(200);
                clear();
                SendAtCommand_Response("AT+QIDEACT\r","DEACT OK",500);
                Delayms(200);
                clear();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same URL then no need, just start from AT+QHTTPPOST.

If another URL is used for another content, then start from AT+GHTTPURL